# With asm how to declare a non-generic class implements generic interface

Tags: java, java-bytecode-asm

For example:

```
class A implements Supplier<String> {

    String get(){
        ....
    }
}
```

I use this code but failed:

```
classWriter.visit(
                V1_8,
                ACC_PUBLIC,
                "abc/A",
                null,
                parentName,
                new String[]{"java/util/function/Supplier"}
        );
```

These interface declareation are all failed:

java/util/function/Supplier

<T:Ljava/lang/String;>java/util/function/Supplier<T>

<T::Ljava/lang/String;>java/util/function/Supplier<T>

<T:Ljava/lang/String;>java/util/function/Supplier<TT>

<T::Ljava/lang/String;>java/util/function/Supplier<TT>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use *javap* to look into how javac would have compiled this class. For your signature, the value would be:

```
Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/util/function/Supplier<Ljava/lang/String;>;
```

As a first argument, you need to provide the non-generic super class and then after the generic values. This goes as the argument that is now `null`, indicating a non-generic class, skipping the attribute.

Note that generic methods require bridge methods to function. You'd need to implement both `Object get()` and `String get()` and simply delegate from the first method to the second. Mark the first method as synthetic and `ACC_BRIDGE`.